Surjectivity of the pushforward of a blowing-up morphism
Given a closed immersion $Z\rightarrow X$ and considering the blowing-up of $X$ at $Z$ and we get $\widetilde{X}$. I'm wondering is the proper pushforward on etale cohomology induced by the blowing-up map from $\widetilde{X}$ to $X$ surjective? If this does not hold in general, can we show the surjectivity of the pushforward from $H^{2n}_{\acute{e}t}(\widetilde{X})$ to $H^{2n}_{\acute{e}t}(X)$ given that $H^{2n-1}_{\acute{e}t}(E)$ is zero $E$ to be the exceptional divisor?
